# dbWriteTable -601 error

Tags: r, db2, rjdbc

I am trying to insert some observations form a R dataframe (R_DATAFRAME) into a db2 dataset (DB2_TABLE) USING `dbWriteTable` function below

```
dbWriteTable(con1P, "DB2_TABLE", R_DATAFRAME, row.names=FALSE)
```

I am getting an -601 error, i did look up 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n601.dita I am unable to understand the description

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate 
(DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-601, SQLSTATE=42710, SQLERRMC=DB2_TABLE;TABLE, DRIVER=4.15.82)
```

Any suggestions on this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `SQL0601N` error means that you're trying to create an object that already exists – in this case `DB_TABLE`.

I believe you need to add the `append=TRUE` option:

```
dbWriteTable(con1P, "DB2_TABLE", R_DATAFRAME, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

Comment: did that, still getting the same error. -601, state = 42710